# Django Cookiecutter Database restore

Tags: django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I'm trying to restore the database with the maintenance script provided. But there is a check in the script which [doesn't](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django/blob/a6ce9f04fff7e90027e105bce72a8706206190cf/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/production/postgres/maintenance/restore#L36) allow me to restore if the user is postgres.

Any reason for that ?

Comment: That would be a question a question of your business rules and/of the developer of the script.

Answer (score 0):

It is a custom to not use the postgres user in this case. Similar to the custom that when operating a linux server, you use a user account instead of the root account.

You can remove the passage from the script if you want to proceed anyway. However, cookiecutter-django should have generated a `.env/.production/.postgres` file with a different username than `postgres`.